# short and char auto unboxing in java

Tags: java, unboxing

```
   HashSet charSet = new HashSet();
   for (char i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      charSet.add(i);
      charSet.remove(i - 1);
    }
    System.out.println(charSet.size());

    HashSet intSet = new HashSet();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        intSet.add(i);
        intSet.remove(i - 1);
    }
    System.out.println(intSet.size());
```

Output is 100 and 1 respectively.

I just realized that short and char do no get auto unboxed in Java. Why didn't the designers think it was important to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually nothing to do with boxing or unboxing.

When you apply an arithmetic operation to a `char`, it is converted to an `int`, as per [JLS §5.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2):

> 2. Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
>    - If either operand is of type `double`, the other is converted to `double`.
>    - Otherwise, if either operand is of type `float`, the other is converted
>        to `float`.
>    - Otherwise, if either operand is of type `long`, the other is converted
>        to `long`.
>    - Otherwise, both operands are converted to type `int`.

Thus, `i - 1` is not a `char`, but an `int`.  And because there are no `Integer`s in your `charSet` (only `Character`s), there is nothing to be removed.  If you were to cast `i - 1` to a `char`, you would get the result you are expecting.

Comment: That's correct. Agreed that `i - 1` is converted into `Integer` but why doesn't autoboxing take place in converting `int` to `Integer` while adding to HashSet

Comment: It does, as the second set is demonstrating.

Comment: Sara, you should also check out Java Generics. Declaring the Set with a Character type parameter would have made it easier to detect this problem

Comment: @Owen I am aware of using generics. This is one of the Java Program Q&A posted in a blog. Was browsing through it and came across this one. Yes, I'll never ignore compiler warning about generics.

Comment: Generics would not help. Even if you declare `HashSet<Character> charSet = new HashSet<>()` the call `charSet.remove(0)` will not generate compile or runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

> I just realized that short and char do no get auto unboxed in Java. Why didn't the designers think it was important to do that?

Whatever has led you to this conclusion, it is incorrect.

Both `short` and `char` can be found in [JLS Sec 5.1.8, Unboxing conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8).

It is easy to write code which demonstrates that both `char` and `short` undergo both autoboxing and auto unboxing:

```
Short ss = (short) 0;  // Autoboxing short to Short
short s = ss;          // Auto unboxing Short to short

Character cc = '\0';   // Autoboxing char to Character
char c = cc;           // Auto unboxing Character to char
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/TiL5Dn)